# simple convergence test $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n+3^n}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, problem-solving

i am pulling my hair out in solving this problem. i know, it is a stupid question but i am not that good at maths, and many thanks for any help

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n+3^n}$

my steps are: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n+3^n} = \frac{2^{n}2+3^{n}3}{2^n+3^n} = help = ?  $  i know, it diverges as the denominator grows faster than the nominator, but the calculation is killing me now

Comment: Hint: divide each term by $3^{n+1}$.

Comment: See also:
[How do I calculate/prove limits for exponential functions: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac {2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n + 3^n}} = 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2564861) and [Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}}{2^{n}+3^{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/459927).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main idea here and in similar problems is to factor out the terms not with the biggest exponents but with the biggest bases. That way you will create terms of the form $(a/b)^n$ where $a<b$ that converge to $0$.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n+3^n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^{n+1}((\frac23)^{n+1}+1)}{3^n((\frac23)^n+1)}=\lim_{n \to \infty} 3\frac{(\frac23)^{n+1}+1}{(\frac23)^n+1}=3
$$
because $(\frac{2}{3})^n\to 0$

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. i was just thinking in some totally wrong way..

Comment: @doniyor: $(\frac{2}{3})^n\to 0$ because $|2/3|<1$.

Comment: @BabakSorouh yes, exactly. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your first step is good. Now divide top and bottom by $3^n$.

Comment: @doniyor: Or factor $3^{n+1}$ in deno. and factor $3^n$ in nomi.

Comment: @BabakSorouh yeah, thanks i got it now :)

Comment: The same strategy is useful for $\frac{2n^5+4n^3-1000n}{3n^5-99n^4-n^2+17}$, and many others, such as replacing top and bottom by their square roots.