# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}}{2^{n}+3^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

I need help with finding

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}}{2^{n}+3^{n}}$

Thanks!

Comment: Try and factor out a $3^n$ on the top and bottom. Then see what you can do.

Comment: Equivalently to the suggestion by Francis Adams, divide top and bottom by $3^n$.

Comment: See also:
[How do I calculate/prove limits for exponential functions: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac {2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n + 3^n}} = 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2564861) and
[simple convergence test $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n+3^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/259365)

Answer (score 2):

Consider

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}}{2^{n}+3^{n}} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n} + 3}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}+1} $$

Now apply

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n =0 \,\,\, |x|<1$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$2^n=_\infty o(3^n)$$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}}{2^{n}+3^{n}} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ 3^{n+1}}{3^{n}}=3$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you proceed
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}}{2^{n}+3^{n}}=  \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^{n+1}((2/3)^{n+1} + 1)}{3^n((2/3)^{n}+1)} = 3.$$

**Note:**

> Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n}{3^n}=0$ the $2^n=o(3^n)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}}{2^{n}+3^{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\frac{2}{3})^{n+1} + 1}{(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{2}{3})^{n}+\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{\,\,1\,\,}{\frac{1}{3}} = 3
$$