# How do I calculate/prove limits for exponential functions: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac {2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n + 3^n}} = 3$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

How do I formally prove that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac {2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n + 3^n}} = 3$. I calculated a few results so I am quite sure that the limit is $3$, but I'm struggling on how to do calculate/proof that correctly.

Comment: Using "monotone convergent theorem".

Comment: I think he divided by $3^n$ on numerator and denominator

Comment: I would write 
$$
\frac {2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n + 3^n}=\frac{2\cdot (\frac23)^n+3}{(\frac23)^n+1} $$

Comment: $2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}\lt 3.2^n+3.3^n$ and ....

Comment: @Jack Ops, I just posted the same as an answer.

Comment: See also: [simple convergence test $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{2^n+3^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/259365) and
[Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}}{2^{n}+3^{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/459927)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$=\frac{2(\frac{2}{3})^n+3}{(\frac{2}{3})^n+1}$$

Comment: I had the same idea but didn't think its very formal.

Comment: I think you have a typo.

Comment: @samjoe: Do you know any rules of limits?

Comment: @samjoe It is the most formal way to solve such a question as you are using the basic limit theorems.

Comment: @Bumblebee yeah, thanks.

Comment: Yeah man I know limit divides over quotient if both exist and denominator doesnt go to zero. But I just thought it isn't formal. Sorry I am a beginner!

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think it would be that easy. But what would I do if I got different exponents like $\frac {(-2)^n}{3^n}$?

Comment: @samjoe: What do you mean by "formal"? Applying a theorem in your calculation *is* formal. One should not have the false impression that "formal" things must be written in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ `:)`

Comment: @Vajk Then it won't exist! It will be sometimes real, imaginary, negative or positive in very short intervals.