# Limit of $\frac{3^n\ +\ (-2)^n}{3^{n + 1}\ +\ (-1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find out the limit of this sequence

$\frac{3^{n}\ +\ \left(-2\right)^{n}}{3^{n\ +\ 1}\ +\ \left(-1\right)^{n}}$

I already know it is $\frac{1}{3}$. My idea was, to potentiate the whole term with $\left(\,\cdots\,\right)^{1/n}$ but this didn't get me there$\ldots$

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $3^n$.

Comment: $\frac{(-2)^n}{3^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{-2}{3}\right)^n\to 0$

Comment: So if i divide it with $3^n$, i've got $\frac{1+(\frac{-2}{3})^n}{3+(\frac{-1}{3})^n}$.  It has a limit, because both minus-signs reverse theirselves for n odd, the fractions go to $0$ and the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: See also this (similar) problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259365/simple-convergence-test-lim-n-to-infty-frac2n13n12n3n

Answer (score 0):

$$3^n \pm 2^n \sim 3^n$$ ($3^n$ is an infinte of an order of magnitude greater than $2^n$)

$$3^{n+1} \pm 1 \sim 3^{n+1}$$ (same reason)

so it is equal to $$\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{3}$$