# Solve this limit: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n+3^n}{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}$

Tags: limits

I could not figure out how to solve this limit:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n+3^n}{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}$$

I aleady checked the step-by-step solution by wolfram, still does not make sense.

Comment: What is $x?$ If $x=n$ the RHS in the title makes no sense, because the limit cannot contain $n.$

Comment: Simply don't care about $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: This is reciprocal of the limit from this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259365/simple-convergence-test-lim-n-to-infty-frac2n13n12n3n

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n+3^n}{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}}\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+1}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}+1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+1}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}+1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{0+1}{0+1}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT :
$$\frac{2^n+3^n}{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{(\frac{2}{3})^n+1}{(\frac{2}{3})^{n+1}+1}\right)$$